# Error when installing Apache2 in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, apt, software-installation, apache-httpd

So I am trying to create a LAMP server, I am trying to install Apache2 and it says it is already installed. I have used the command below and the server says is already installed and shows this(picture below).

```
sudo apt-get install apache2
```

[image: after trying the command]

Now when I want to check Apache2 is working correctly by using my IP address, it doesn't show the Apache2 default page and doesn't load. I have already tried to uninstall it and install it again but it hasn't fixed this. I would appreciate some feedback on how to fix this. Thank you.

Comment: Having a look in the `/var/log/apache2` logs can be useful. The `apachectl restart` command can restart your Apache and enventually show useful error messages.

Comment: Ok I did what you mentioned and I get this weird stuff in the apache2 directory. So there are only three files access.log error.log and other _vhosts_access.log. What does it mean?

Comment: The `access.log` log each request sent by Apache, excluding virtual hosts. On the opposite, `other_vhost_access.log` log each request to a virtual host.

The `error.log` trace all errors with more details (not only requests). 

With the `access.log` we can see if Apache has viewed the request you try. (You have only said it can't load the default page... but is it a navigator error page ? an Apache error page ?). The `error.log` can give interesting information.

The `apachectl restart` can give on your console some other informations, especially if Apache doesn't start.

Comment: You should send us the content of these files and the result of `apachectl restart`.

Comment: [Please don't post images of text](http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text).  Copy and paste the text itself **into your question** and format it as code by selecting it and pressing Ctrl-K or by using the editor's `{}` icon.